# Why can't I import from a python file one up from existing package?

Tags: python, import, flask, circular-dependency

In a website I'm building with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) I've got structure like this:

```
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── ticket_scanner
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── filehelper.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── all the templates are here..
│   └── views.py
└── run.py
```

I now want to import `models` into `ticket_scanner/__init__.py`. I tried to do this using the following import statements (with the errors behind them):

```
from .. import models  # ImportError: cannot import name models
from . import models  # ImportError: cannot import name models
import models  # ImportError: No module named models
from ..models import ImageHash  # ImportError: cannot import name ImageHash
```

As you can see it refuses to import from the `models.py` file. I do have circular imports in these files, but I wouldn't know where it goes wrong. Below this message I pasted the full stacktrace of my first attempt (`from .. import models`).

Does anybody know what I'm dong wrong here? All tips are welcome!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/kramer65/repos/fts/app/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import views, models
  File "/Users/kramer65/repos/fts/app/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from models import Ticket
  File "/Users/kramer65/repos/fts/app/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ticket_scanner import filehelper, pdf as pdf_helper, util
  File "/Users/kramer65/repos/fts/app/ticket_scanner/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .. import models
ImportError: cannot import name models
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether relative imports like these work at all. But in my projects, I put a simple `setup.py` in the top directory that installs the entire project. Then you can do `python setup.py develop` and import from the project.

Also I never put any code into the `__init__.py`. I import everything in the scripts. Not sure if that would ease your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you use `from app import models` or `from app.models import ImageHash`